# When I try to play tabs, my fingerpicking sounds robotic

Tags: fingering

Its more like when I place fingers or maybe both, I produce clear tones and all, but the when I try to play something that should be like in line nice and steady, I play it like I m breaking it on shorter parts, like I said robotic, and its not that I just started, I can play chord progressions fairly well and place all finger relatively fast, but when I play tabs it sounds like in the title.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't get it to sound legato, continuous and all notes connected to each other? If not, what do you mean? Can you provide an audio example what it sounds like if you play, say, the notes C and D in a robotic way, and then the same two notes in a non-robotic way?

Comment: What about not playing tabs?  I find the question confusing.  There is nothing special about a tab that would make your playing different so I'd guess it's trying to play something new.  No matter how good you get a new piece needs to be approached like it's the first time.  You have a new pattern to get in the muscle memory.

Comment: I agree the question is confusing as stated. Assuming you mean, as @piiperi said "Do you mean that you can't get it to sound legato, continuous and all notes connected to each other?" it's a question of practice and finger strength.

Comment: If it is sight reading, then just take it slow enough to be comfortable.  Bring out the melody and be sure to feel the beat or the pulse.  That is most important.  If it still sounds broken up or robotic, then take the whole piece slower until you can manage all the way through in a musical way.  Once achieve, you can begin to notch up the speed.

Comment: I have found that when I am seated near the computer and trying to learn a new piece via tabs, I am also in the same boat. 

But when I stand up and walk away from the chair and the computer (or music stand) and pace around a bit, it become more fluid and natural. Especially when I sing the notes and/or sing the song lyrics. 

This requires that you have the guitar strapped on, of course.
And centered around your mid-belly, not down low. 

In freeing yourself from the visual reference, you become free to literally walk it through, and make the piece your own.

Comment: @piiperi exactly cant get it to sound legato.